# Iterator and chunksize in HDFStore.select: "Memory error"

Tags: python, pandas, memory, iterator, hdfstore

To my understanding, `HDFStore.select` is *the* tool to use for selecting from large data sets. However, when trying to loop over chunks using `chunksize` and `iterator=True`,  the iterator itself becomes a very large object once the underlying dataset is large enough, and I don't understand **why** the iterator object is large and what kind of information it contains that it has to become so large.

I have a very large `HDFStore` structure (7 bn rows, 420 GB on-disk), which I would like to iterate by chunks:

```
iterator = HDFStore.select('df', iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize)

for i, chunk in enumerate(iterator):
    # some code to apply to each chunk
```

When I run this code for a relatively small file  - everything works fine. 
However, when I try to apply it to the 7 bn row database, I get a `Memory Error` when computing iterator. I have 32 GB RAM.

I would like to have a generator to create chunks on the go, which doesn't store so much into RAM, for example:

```
iteratorGenerator = lambda: HDFStore.select('df', iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize)

for i, chunk in enumerate(iteratorGenerator):
    # some code to apply to each chunk
```

but `iteratorGenerator` is not iterable, so this doesn't work either.

I could potentially loop the `HDFStore.select` over `start` and `stop` rows, but I thought that there should be a more elegant way to iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that same problem with a (only) 30GB file, and apparently you can solve it by forcing the garbage collector to do its job... collect! :P
PS: Also you don't need a lambda for that, the select call will return an iterator, just loop over it, like you did i the first code block.

```
with pd.HDFStore(file_path, mode='a') as store:
    # All you need is the chunksize
    # not the iterator=True
    iterator = store.select('df', chunksize=chunksize)

    for i, chunk in enumerate(iterator):

        # some code to apply to each chunk

        # magic line, that solved my memory problem
        # You also need "import gc" for this
        gc.collect()
```